# Match capital letters and fill in with subsequent letters until certain string length

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a camel-cased string, for example: `JustAString`.

I would like to form strings of **length 4** by following these rules:

- grab all capital letters;
- if more than 4 capital letters, keep only the first 4;
- if less than 4 capital letters, capitalize and add letters that follow the *last* capital letter, until the length becomes 4.

Here are the 3 cases that may happen:

- `ThisIsMyString` will yield `TIMS` (capitals);
- `ThisIsOneVeryLongString` will yield `TIOV` (first 4 capitals);
- `MyString` will yield `MSTR` (capitals + `tr` capitalized).

I managed to solve the first two cases with this snippet:

```
str.scan(/[A-Z]/).first(4).join
```

However, I am not quite sure how can I best modify the above snippet to handle the last case also (or even try something different).

P.S.: The string is guaranteed to have at least a capital and 4 characters. However, if theoretically a capital is missing, the first 4 characters should be taken into consideration. If there aren't 4 characters, the missing characters may be filled in with the first alphabet characters (`abcd`). But, as mentioned, these 2 edge cases won't normally happen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace any character(s) that precedes a capital with nothing, then grab the first 4 characters and upcase:

`str.gsub(/[^A-Z]+([A-Z])/){$1}[0..3].upcase`

This handles no capitals too. As for the edge case of not enough chars, you could append "abcd" but I'd find it cleaner just to do this in a separate line after the fact: `output_string = (output_string + "abcd")[0..3] if output_string.length < 4`. This is reads much cleaner and performs (inconsequentially) better if this is really a rare edge case.

Comment: Nice one, Andrew. You could also write `str.gsub(/[^A-Z]+([A-Z])/,'\1')[0,4].upcase`.

Comment: This is indeed very neat! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution:

```
((str.scan(/[A-Z]/)[0..-2] + str.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*$/)).join + "abcd")[0, 4].upcase
```

And here it is with comments:

```
(
  (
    str.scan(/[A-Z]/)[0..-2] + # All but the last capital letter
    str.scan(/[A-Z]?[^A-Z]*$/)  # The last capital letter, if any, plus trailing lowercase letters
  ).join +
  "abcd"
)[0, 4]. # Take the first 4 chars, 4 capitals if we have them, then trailing lowercase if we have those, then the "abcd" filler
upcase # upcase any trailing lowercase letters we included
```

Comment: It looks interesting. Is there a way to use a single regex? I am not sure how you can write a "all occurrences but the last one" regex.

Comment: You can match an unknown number of capital letters possibly separated by lowercase letters in a single regex, but there's no way to capture only the capitals.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods.

**#1 Use [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) with a regex, followed by [String#upcase](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-upcase) and [String#[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)**

```
R = /
    [a-z]           # match a lower case letter
    (?=[a-z]*[A-Z]) # match >= 0 lower case letters followed by an upper case letter
                    # in a positive lookahead 
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode

def get_caps(str, n)
  str.gsub(R,"").upcase[0,4]
end

get_caps("ThisIsMyString", 4)          #=> "TIMS"
get_caps("ThisIsOneVeryLongString", 4) #=> "TIOV"
get_caps("MyString", 4)                #=> "MSTR"
get_caps("abcde", 4)                   #=> "ABCD"
get_caps("", 4)                        #=> ""
get_caps("AbcdefGh", 4)                #=> "AGH"
```

**#2 Determine the index of the last capital letter and then build the string**

```
def get_caps(str, n)
  idx = str.rindex(/[A-Z]/)
  return str[0,4].upcase if idx.nil?
  str.each_char.with_index.with_object('') { |(c,i),s|
    s << c.upcase if (s.size < n && (i > idx || c == c.upcase)) }
end

get_caps("ThisIsMyString", 4)          #=> "TIMS"
get_caps("ThisIsOneVeryLongString", 4) #=> "TIOV"
get_caps("MyString", 4)                #=> "MSTR"
get_caps("abcde", 4)                   #=> "ABCD"
get_caps("", 4)                        #=> ""
get_caps("AbcdefGh", 4)                #=> "AGH"
```

If you wish to return `nil` if the string returned contains fewer than `n` characters, add that check to the methods.